# Android Metro-Style Design Pattern

Tags: android, modern-ui

I'm designing a Metro-Style Android application.
Tiles, Groups & Scrolls are done!

For who're not familiar with Metro-Style (aka Modern UI), please take a look at the following picture.

[image: Modern UI]

**Question :**
What's the best (performance wise) design pattern for sorting tiles dynamically in 2 rows & multiple columns ?

```
- HorizontalScrollView
- - LinearLayout  
- - - Every 2 tiles have same weight
```

Or

```
- HorizontalScrollView
- - TableLayout
- - - Every 2 tiles have same row
```

Or

```
- Something else ?
```

Comment: What about the ones that span 2 columns?

Comment: mmmmm Maybe later, I'm just searching for 2 rows multiple (non-spanning) columns.

Comment: What you are thinking is right. You can use HorizontalScrollView as parent. But I will suggest you to have a look at https://github.com/dlew/android-gridlayout. This GridView will provide you a custom design with Row and Column wise. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this layout:

| Relative Layout

|--> HorizontalScrollView

|--|--> LinearLayout *(showDivider=middle|beginning|end, and divider drawable=50x1])*

|--|--|--> TableLayout *(With weight=1)*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#011a41"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:divider="@drawable/divider"
            android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end" >

            <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow6" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow7" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow8" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/toggleButton1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="ToggleButton" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```